# Why am I having trouble loading Ubuntu alongside Windows as an application?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, troubleshooting, multi-boot

I have two good CD ISO files. Both load OK, but when I boot to Ubuntu the screen is fragmented by dozens of white lines. Program works but is useless.

I'm running Windows XP SP3 on D201GLY MB, CELERON CPU 220 1.02 GHZ, 512 RAM

What could be my problem? CPU? Not enough RAM? Or maybe even the graphics card?
to be clearer i am trying to load either ubuntu 8.04 or 9.04 inside windows as an aplication from known GOOD cd's. trying to load with the wubi installer that is loaded on the cd's. sis mirage graphics 32mb vid prosser sis 662.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.  Are you booting from an Ubuntu CD image in Virtual PC?  Did you burn one of the ISO images to CD and boot off that, separately from XP?  Since you're seeing video problems, what video chipset is in your PC?

Comment: trying to load as an application WITHIN windows from known to be good cd's. ubuntu 8.04 or 9.04. same problem either one. using the installer on the cd. sis mirage graphics 32mb. video prosser sis 662 driver version 6.14.10.3800. how can i set up video card ? can not find any guidance on ubuntu/linux sites.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the video card isn;t setup properly under ubuntu. What kind of a video card are you using? Which version of ubuntu?

You need to clerify a bit more as the title of this question doesnt make a whole lot of sense, how are you able to load Ubuntu alongside Windows as an application? Are you using Wubi?

Comment: using wubi installer that is on the cd. trying to install as an aplication within windows. sis mirage graphics 32 mb vid pros sis 662. cd's are known to be good. ubuntu 8.04/9.04. both give same problem.

Comment: how can i set up video card ? no guidance i can find on ubuntu site's.

Comment: The default installed on the CD is used to install an OS and not as an application.

As far as installing/updating a video driver - i recommend you either take the time to learn or work around this issue. Getting it to work means getting your hands dirty and doing a lot of reading. A work around would be to simply install One of the Virtual Environments: Microsoft Virtual PC or suns virtual Box and install Linux.. This will give you windows and linux at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Wubi's "Safe Graphics" mode?

From http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=438486:

> right after you select "ubuntu" from
>   the menu, press ESC. It should show up
>   a menu entry, then select the one that
>   says "safe mode". If only 1 option is
>   available, select that one, and press
>   ESC immediately afterwards, and you
>   should get the correct menu. If
>   there's still only 1 option after the
>   2nd menu, press "e" to edit, and at
>   the end of the line that says "kernel"
>   remove "quiet" and "splash", add
>   "single", press enter, and press b to
>   boot.
>
> Another way would just be to let it
>   boot until it gets to the black
>   screen, and press Ctrl-Alt-F1, or
>   Ctrl-Alt-F2, login, enter "sudo -s"
>   and it'll have the same result